# Stuck in a stupid phase of coding game of life

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I've been trying to code game of life by my own as I want to learn python and I thought that could be a good practice and I have just finish except I need to pass a variable to another method but I really dont know how I know it could seem dumb
but wait a bit and see the code is not that easy as it sound unless for me

```
import random,time
f=3
c=3
contador = 0
tablero = []
tablero_dibujado = []

class juego(object):

    def tablero(self): #Create the Board
        for i in range(f):
            tablero.append([0]*c)
            tablero_dibujado.append([0]*c)

    def rellenar_tablero_random(self): #Fill the board with random 0 and 1
        for i in range(f):
            for j in range(c):
                tablero[i][j] = random.randint(0,1)
        print(tablero)

    def rellenar_tablero_manual(self): #Just to fill the board manually if I want for some reason
        tablero[0][1] = 1
        for i in range(2):
            tablero[1][i] = 1
        print(tablero)

    def distancia_vecino(self,cell_f,cell_c):   #Measure Distance for possible neighbours
        distancia_vecino = [(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1)]
        for i in range(8):
            string = distancia_vecino[i]
            comparar_string = str(string)
            x,y = comparar_string.split(",")
            x = str(x).replace(",","")
            y = str(y).replace(",","")
            x = x.replace("(","")
            y = y.replace(")","")
            y = y.replace(" ","")
            x = int(x) + cell_f
            y = int(y) + cell_c

            if x>=f or x<0:
                continue
            else:
                if y>=c or y<0:
                    continue
                else:
                    game.detectar_vecino(cell_f,cell_c,x,y)
        game.vida(cell_f,cell_c)

    def detectar_vecino(self, cell_f, cell_c, x, y):    #Check how many neighboards do I have
        vecinos = 0

        if tablero[cell_f][cell_c] == 1:
            if tablero[cell_f][cell_c] == tablero[x][y]:
                vecinos+=1
        else:
            if tablero[cell_f][cell_c] != tablero[x][y]:
                vecinos+=1
        contador = contador + vecinos

    def iterar_tablero(self): #Just to iterate all the board to check the values
        for i in range(f):
            for j in range(c):
                game.distancia_vecino(i,j)
        a = input() #In order to the screen dont close after executing it

    def vida(self, cell_f, cell_c): #Check if they are alive and if they should be alive or dead

        print(contador)
        if tablero[cell_f][cell_c] == 1:
            if contador > 3 or contador < 2:
                tablero[cell_f][cell_c] = 0
        else:
            if contador == 3:
                tablero[cell_f][cell_c] = 1

        game.dibujar_tablero()

    def dibujar_tablero(self): #Draw the board in a more clearly way
        contador1 = 0
        for i in range(f):
            for j in range(c):
                if tablero[i][j] == 1:
                     tablero_dibujado[i][j] = "§"
                else:
                     tablero_dibujado[i][j] = "■"

        for i in tablero_dibujado:
            print(" ")
            for j in i:
                print(j, end=" ")
        print("")
        time.sleep(2)


game = juego()
game.tablero()
game.rellenar_tablero_manual()
game.iterar_tablero()
```

What I need is that in detectar_vecino have to get all the neighbour of a cell in the board and the problem is that doing it I got : local variable 'contador' referenced before assignment.  And I know why it happen.However I couldnt find any alternative way of doing it so please if anyone know how can I solve it.

I just want to clarify that this isnt any work from anywhere,Im doing it just by my own as a hobby and with this I just want to finish with thank you for your time I appreciate it

Comment: If you are using python3 then write this line `global contador` before using that variable in the `detectar_vecino` function.

Comment: It would make your code easier to read for most of the people here if you used English names for your variables and functions. Although I've written quite a few Life programs over the years I'm not quite sure of your logic, but I guess you could set `contador = 0`, or pass the initial value in to `detectar_vecino` via an argument. Or you could follow Shreyash S Sarnayak's suggestion and make it a global, although it's better if you can avoid using mutable globals because they break program modularity, and make programs harder to debug.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing all that crazy string stuff with `comparar_string`. That's slow and inefficient. It would be bad enough if your program just did it once, but you do it inside a loop inside a function that gets called for every cell on the board! You should just use indexing to access the values in that list of tuples. BTW, it's not a good idea to have a variable name like `distancia_vecino` with the same name as the function it's defined in.

Comment: To get those x & y values you can simply do `x, y = distancia_vecino[i]`

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak  Finally I decided to do what you told me and it work right so thank you

Comment: @PM2Ring As i said in the comment before I did the global variable as an argument it was a bit hard in the way I wrote the code and in reference with the crazy thing I did its already solved thank you I didnt know what I was thinking and just to finish next time I will write in English for an easier understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line `global contador` like below

```
def detectar_vecino(self, cell_f, cell_c, x, y):
    global contador   # Add this line.
    vecinos = 0

    if tablero[cell_f][cell_c] == 1:
        if tablero[cell_f][cell_c] == tablero[x][y]:
            vecinos+=1
    else:
        if tablero[cell_f][cell_c] != tablero[x][y]:
            vecinos+=1
    contador = contador + vecinos
```